# Spring Security - @secured AuthorizationManager and AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm working with spring security 5.8.4 to prepare spring 6 migration.

I have created an custom AuthorizationManager

```
public class CustomAuthorizationManager implements AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> {
...
}
```

I declare bean with this code

```
    @Bean
    public Advisor customAuthorize() {
        Pointcut pattern = new AnnotationMatchingPointcut(null, Secured.class, true);
        AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor interceptor = new AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor(pattern, authorizationManager);
        interceptor.setOrder(AuthorizationInterceptorsOrder.SECURED.getOrder() - 1);
        return interceptor;
    }
```

I add breakpoint on AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor spring class.

When I call a web service, I can see it is okay because I have the CustomAuthorizationManager break and the default SecuredAuthorizationManager spring class.

But when my controller call the service, I have only the SecuredAuthorizationManager break and not my CustomAuthorizationManager (I have to deal with legacy code and role, and it's for this I use CustomAuthorizationManager).

I don't understand why the CustomAuthorizationManager was called only on controller but not service.

Someone can please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I will not use spring security and I will disable this

```
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = false, prePostEnabled = false)
```

I will use a custom aspect